# How do I boot over LAN/PXE without a router?

Tags: boot, pxe

I have 2 computers connected by Ethernet I would like to boot one from the other over PXE using Ethernet.

Do I have to have a router to do so or can I skip it?  I would like to boot a linux distro on the other computer.

Comment: Are you talking about something like [Wake on LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)?

Comment: @MrPublic I was aware of such so no.  I'm trying to figure out if I can boot between 2 computers without a router.  Wake on LAN is cool though.  Forgive me I may have misunderstood you.

Comment: Pxe boot? What's the other PC run? What sorta hardware?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes PXE boot is the official name.  Anything thats free preferable.  Currently its running W7 and ubuntu.  I was thinking maybe I could by one of those mini routers if they are available but I haven't found many small ones.

Comment: Network booting does not require a router.  It's not one of the functions of a router in a network.  You do need a server that will offer up the boot images.  Linux can use NFS or TFTP or DHCP to access/boot-from the server.

Comment: @sawdust can you walk me through the steps of booting something then?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by just connecting both PCs Ethernet cards with a [Crossover Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) cable; no router/switch/hub needed.

Also you can easily set up a whole PXE environment for booting/installing Windows and Linux with [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html) (I'm related to Serva development)

Comment: What software do I run through the crossover ethernet cable then?

Comment: @William, this is an old answer, today most NICs do not need the crossover cable for a back-to-back connection, they detect when it happens and act accordingly.
When the connection is done you can run any software you want, if you need a PXE server you can use [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html)